# Contact github , sourcetree

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

github, A invites B to the repository, showing two from the github page of B (the second is the invited store), as shown in picture 1, but only the private repository is visible like the second one in B's sourcetree, The repository is invisible.

What should I do?

Additional content: Do I need to give more titles than Collaborators & teams?

[Collaborators & teams image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxPwM.png)

Comment: What about contacting the GitHub support?

Comment: The source tree is just a GUI tool I don't think it will distinguish based on the private and public repository. Could you please check the permissions once? if A also gives the sufficient permission to B.

Comment: @Shivang Agarwal You have entered additional content.
Is there any place for you to give me additional suggestions beyond Collaborators & teams?